# How I create a Read More button inside a table?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, foreach

```
<?php $counter = 0 ?>
<table>
  <?php foreach($attributes as $a): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php $a['name']?></td>
    <td><?php $a['Price']?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php $counter++;
    if ($counter > 3) ?> <!-- What to do here? -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

In a PHP Block like this, I would like to got a Read More button after three **tr** elements, and when I click the button show all the rest of elements...

Something to do with PHP?

Comment: you can do it using ajax. on that button click (Read More) add new trs using ajax call. Click on this link : [/load-more-data-using-jquery-ajax-php-from-database](http://www.codexworld.com/load-more-data-using-jquery-ajax-php-from-database/) it's a example of load more / read more data from database and put it in html.

Answer (score 0):

No, it has nothing to do with php. You need JavaScript to implement this if you don't want to reload the whole page.

In PHP you could print the short and the long version into separate `div`s and then use the following JS-Code on the View-More-Button:

```
document.getElementById("shortId").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("longId").style.display = "block";
```